# External login using Identity Server 3 - Setting Given Name claim from facebook

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, owin, identityserver3

Im trying to setup identityserver to be able to login with facebook. All works fine except I cant retrieve any of the user info from facebook.The mvc app is expected a givenname and lastname claim.  I have added a scope to public_profile but do not get it back.

After lots of research it seems like I might need to setup a UserService to do this but am not sure how to do this.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code to configure the external providers in the statup of the idenity server app:

```
private void ConfigureIdenityProviders (IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
    {

        var facebookOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Facebook",
            Caption = "Sign in with Facebook",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
            AppId = "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            AppSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",



            Provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnAuthenticated =  (context) =>
                {

                    // Problem here - there is no last_name returned
                       JToken lastname;
                    if (context.User.TryGetValue("last_name", out lastname))
                    {
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName, lastname.ToString()));
                    }

                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("role", "Guest"));

                    return Task.FromResult(0);

                }

            }
        };

         facebookOptions.Scope.Add("public_profile");
        facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");


        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up using the facebook graph to get the user profile.

A user service may be another way to do it but this works for me.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        var result = client.GetAsync("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=first_name,last_name&access_token=" + context.AccessToken).Result;


                        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            var userInformation = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                            var fbUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookUser>(userInformation);
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName, fbUser.first_name));
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName, fbUser.last_name));
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("role", "Guest"));
                        }

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Any claims you get back from Facebook will be passed along to your custom user service's `AuthenticateExternal` method. At that point they're your claims to do whatever you want to with.

If you're not getting the claims you want from Facebook, I'd suggest building a standalone MVC app to get that problem sorted out first.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get access token from FB unless you modify your Provider as follows

```
OnAuthenticated = context =>
               {
context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
return Task.FromResult(true);
  }
```

After you get the token use call fb with the token and get the given_name